# Menu icon not visible in ion-navbar Ionic 2

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

`<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar hideBackButton>
    <ion-title>
      Test
    </ion-title>
    <button menuToggle>
    <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
  </button>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>`
I'm able to drag and close the menu but the menu button isn't getting added to the navbar.

Comment: Is this issue resolved?

Comment: Yes.Check the accepted answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add only one line

`this.navCtrl.setRoot(Page1);`

to display the menu icon in the nav bar.

Add this line on the page that comes before the user is navigated to the 'Page1' page.

Comment: where to put this line?

Comment: You can add this line to previous page of Page 1 where you call the Page 1

Comment: @Siddhesh Thank you, it worked. Can I know what is happening in the background?

Comment: Whenever we directly use side menu project in app.component.ts i observed that that side menu component called by **setRoot(pagename)**. So I tried in my project and it's work.

Comment: Just in case anyone else tries to do this, I added the line of code to set the root and then I tried to navigate to the same page, which caused the menu button to disappear again. Simply calling the setRoot function will do the trick of navigating you to the page and setting it as the root.

Answer (score 2):

try below code in ionic 3 :

```
        <ion-header>
          <ion-toolbar color="danger">
            <ion-title>
              Home
            </ion-title>
            <ion-buttons>
             <button ion-button icon-only menuToggle>
              <ion-icon name='menu'></ion-icon>
            </button>
           </ion-buttons>
        </ion-toolbar>
     </ion-header>
```

Answer (score -1):

Add this code in your menu template

```
<ion-side-menu-content  >
  <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable custom-nav-bar">

  <ion-nav-back-button>
  </ion-nav-back-button>

  <ion-nav-buttons side="left" >
    <button class="button button-icon ion-grid" menu-toggle="left">
    </button>
  </ion-nav-buttons>
 </ion-nav-bar>

<ion-nav-view name="menuContent"></ion-nav-view>
</ion-side-menu-content>
```

This will add toggle menu button on the nav bar

Comment: Error:'ion-nav-back-button' is not a known element.

Comment: I'm using Ionic 2